# How to check an object contains a set of properties

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'll start this by saying, I understand there are many ways to do this. This question is an effort to compare different version.

I also understand we're looking for SO to be a QA site, not a QAAAAAAA... site.

So I'll refine the question to make it more focused and end up with one answer.

Given an object:

`var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};`

Find out if the following keys are present:

`var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']; // 'd' would be flagged although a boolean would suffice`

Ideally I'd like to do this in ES5, but ES6 is more than welcome.

Ideally without the use of lodash, but it's more than welcome.

I'm sure there's a lovely combination of the native Array methods that'll work:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

The aim is to have a function or line of code that's small and concise rather than something like:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var found = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])) {
    found--;
  }
}
console.log("Missing:", found);
```

I'll wade in with the first offering:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

var allPresent = Object.keys(obj).filter(function(item) {
  return keys.indexOf(item) !== -1;
}).length === keys.length;

console.log("All present:", allPresent);
```

Comment: Try `_.difference` in lodash

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).filter(e => keys.indexOf(item) !== -1);`

Comment: If I removed my attempt and pretended not to know any way to do it, would it still need moving to CR?

Comment: Maybe. I'd like to stick to the rules but I find them funny at times. It's why I asked for a more concise way of writing it. It's already garnered some good responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```js
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

alert(keys.every(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allPresent = keys.reduce(function ( acc, next ) {
    return !acc || obj.hasOwnProperty(next);
}, true);
```

Although Amits answer is probably even smaller and preferred for browsers that support 'every'. (should be all of them by now)

Comment: `Array.prototype.every` outdates `Array.prototype.reduce` and is supported in a (insignificant) larger installed base (JS1.6 vs JS1.8).

Comment: Oh awesome, thanks! Didn't know that. For some reason i thought every was added when they added find. But MDN knows all. :)

Answer (score -1):

Given object:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
    keys = ['a','b'];
```

You can check if it contains key 'a' using this:

```
Object.keys( obj ).indexOf('a') !== -1
```

Thanks for comments here is full answer to check what OP requested for full equality:

```
JSON.stringify( Object.keys( obj ) ) === JSON.stringify( keys )
```

Or partial equality

```
JSON.stringify( Object.keys( obj ) ).indexOf( JSON.stringify( keys ) ) !== -1
```

Comment: Although I didn't downvote you, to get the requested result, you still need to use a loop, which is identical to the last example the OP gave.

Comment: thanks guys i missed the point my bad, i edited the answer though

Comment: The solution in your edit doesn't work. It can work accidentally but if the keys are in the array in different order, or if there are keys in between, it won't work.

Comment: may be .sort() can help? but it becomes too inefficient then i think

Comment: No, it can't. The keys in between are still a problem.